# How can we give placeholder for a float field in django forms?

Tags: django, django-forms

Is is possible to give placeholder for a float field in django forms?

I know that We can easily give placeholder for a char field in django like below,

```
materials_name = forms.CharField(required=False,max_length=200,label= "Material Name", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Material name'}))
```

Like this how can i give placeholder for a float field in django forms?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it in the same way:

```
materials_float = forms.FloatField(required=False,label= "Material Name", widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Material float'}))
```

Or:

```
materials_decimal = forms.DecimalField(required=False,label= "Material Name", widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Material decimal'}))
```

just change Field

**UPDATE:** As @olofom requested, the widget has been replaced by `NumberInput` to render to `number` field in HTML

Comment: DW becuase it changed his initial requirements, kinda. It should at least, but your comment fixes it and I change my vote if you edit it in your answer (I can't otherwise btw) :)